# Black & White Scotsman riddle

Tags: riddle

> Gear makes a record with me,
>   Stephen, in UK, makes a record with me.
>   
>   I'm not the reason of coloured dream,
>   With me the first ghost telling stories to others.
>   
>   Scotsman show me a picture first time,
>   Guess me who I am?

No partial answers please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is fairly clearly

> television

although the details are not so clear.

> Gear makes a record with me,

is probably a reference to

> Top Gear

Perhaps the dodgem world speed record.

> Stephen, in UK, makes a record with me.

Almost certainly refers to

> Stephen Fry's record for the most f-words in 90 seconds

> I'm not the reason of coloured dream,
>   With me the first ghost telling stories to others.

Probably refers to the black and white origins also mentioned in the title.

> Scotsman show me a picture first time,

> John Logie Baird

Comment: Its correct! :)

Answer (score 3):

I might be wildly off, but here is the answer:

> Is it BBC
>
>  The gear and stephen correspond to Top gear and Stephen Fry. The coloured dream is bbc switching from black and white picture to color picture. The ghost refers to "The Ghost stories of Christmas" which aired in bbc. And the scotsman refers to the flying scotsman that is airing on bbc.

Comment: you are very close but this is not the correct answer :). See around.

Comment: Fixed the spoiler tags for you :) You just had them the wrong way round (and p.s. you can have a line break by adding to spaces at the ned of a line or by using <br>)